# Baking displacement map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I have created a node based procedural displacement on a mesh. How can I now bake a displacement map from that in cycles?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smRJH4kJgFo

Comment: Thanks for the link, iv never done that before. But I'm not trying to Bake a normal / bump from displacement in Blender cycles. I'm trying to "create"  bake a displacement map from a procedural displacement node setup.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut-KYKbnj8A&feature=youtu.be&t=2m24s